# CSS transitions - overflow and box-shadow issues

Tags: css

I am making a simple slide up/slide down transition.

The setup is simple - I have a parent `form` element that has `overflow: hidden; max-height: 0; transition: 200ms, all;` applied to it and a child `fieldset` that has `border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 0; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #aaa;`. In order to do the slide down effect, I apply a class to a parent of `form` which in turn changes its css to `max-height: 100px; overflow: visible;`.

Here is a fiddle of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lqmrzgw/

My problem is due to me having to set `overflow: visible` on the open state, you can see the form 'fading in' rather than just sliding down (click view 1 to see this). If I take off `overflow: visible` then the `box-shadow` is not visible.

How can I get round this issue and create my slide up/slide down transition and keep the `box-shadow` visible?

My full html:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>view 1</p>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>a label</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br/>
                    <label>a label</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>view 2</p>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>a label</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br/>
                    <label>a label</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Full css:

```
/* setup */
.container { margin: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
li:last-of-type { border-bottom: none; padding-bottom: 0; }
fieldset { border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 0; padding: 10px; }
p { cursor: pointer; transition: 200ms, all; padding: 15px; margin: 0; }
p:hover { background: #fff6e3; }
.open p { background: #fff6e3; }

/* show/hide */

form { overflow: hidden; max-height: 0; transition: 200ms, all; }
.open form { max-height: 100px; overflow: visible; transition: 200ms, all; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #aaa; }
```

js:

```
$('p').click(function(e){
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('open'); 
});
```

Comment: Hey, this question has been flagged to be closed. I'm going to vote to keep it open, but it would be helpful if you could do a little work on it to justify me spending my time doing this. The main problem is that your code is on jsfiddle, not embedded in the quesiton (see: [ask] for details on this). SO now offers the same capabilities as jsfiddle, so you don't need to go offsite any more. The problem with having your code only on jsfiddle is that if that site disappears your question will become unreadable.

Comment: I see the `box-shadow` without `overflow:visible`. Is it just me? http://jsfiddle.net/1Lqmrzgw/1/

Comment: @EngineerDollery - I will copy the code over.

Comment: @showdev - I see it as well now, that's very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #aaa;
```

to:

```
.open form { max-height: 100px; transition: 200ms, all; overlay:visible;}
```

like this:

```
.open form { max-height: 100px; transition: 200ms, all; overlay:visible; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #aaa; }
```

Comment: applying the shadow to the `form` isn't an option for me, it has to stay on the `fieldset`. The `form` is merely a container.

Comment: Increase the margin of the fieldset from 0 to e.g. 5px

Comment: Sorry, that won't work either. I have updated my jsfiddle slightly so it is slightly more inline with my actual design.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to contain the form fields inside the fieldset and made the shadow play nicer. I used a specific height, so it doesn't size the form to the content, but at least it's a form that slides out so you have a starting point.

Put the shadow on the form element instead, and use `height` instead of `max-height`:

```
form { height: 0; transition: 500ms, all; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #aaa; }
.open form { height: 100px; transition: 500ms, all; }
```

Put the `overflow: hidden` on the `fieldset` and make it the full height of the form, and add another element inside the `fieldset` that you can style with border and padding:

```
fieldset { overflow: hidden; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
fieldset > div { height: 80px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/k9nj3s43/5/

(I slowed down the transitions to better see exactly what's happening.)

Comment: Thanks for this but as I said to Flux, the shadow needs to stay on the `fieldset`. Also, I do not know exactly how tall my form will be, hence the use of `max-height`. I would normally use `height: auto` but that can't be used with css transitions.

Comment: @boz: You can add more containers to keep the shadow on the fieldset, but the dynamic height is tricky...

Comment: The `max-height` takes care of it up to a point. There will be issues if one of the forms is huge and the others are not but I will cross that bridge when I come to it. I think I can sort the shadow with some negative margins on the parent `form`.